# Imagemagick auto create duplicate file

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, favicon

I downloaded the icon file from http://www.freeiconsweb.com/favicon.ico. I try to convert ico file to png as below : -

```
im.convert(['favicon.ico', '-format', '16x16+0+0', 'favicon.png'], function (err, stdout, stderr) {

});
```

Result :
It's create two png file for me. `favicon-0.png` and `favicon-1.png`.

Correct result:
It should be create one file only that is `favicon.png`.

Anyone know about the why imagemagick create two file ?

Answer (score 4):

An ico file can contain multiple images, a png cannot, so ImageMagick makes a png for each image in the ico file.

From [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_%28file_format%29) (emphasis mine):

> The ICO file format is an image file format for computer icons in Microsoft Windows. **ICO files contain one or more small images at multiple sizes and color depths**, such that they may be scaled appropriately.

To get only a single image, you'd have to specify which one you want.  For help with that, see the (command line) documentation [on reading particular frames of an image](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#read_frames).